# Read 32 bit binary numbers in java

Tags: java

I am trying to read five 32-bit binary numbers and print them as int.  Here is my code:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        int count = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            byte[] input = file.getBytes();
            String bin=Integer.toBinaryString(0xFF & input[i] | 0x100).substring(1);
            System.out.println(bin);
```

I am getting this:

```
01010011
01101110
00110011
01011111
01010010
```

What am I doing wrong?  thanks

Comment: Read the javadoc of `toBinaryString`.

Comment: @MikeSamuel  Big endian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to read five *big-endian* 32-bit integers, then I suggest that you use `DataInputStream`, e.g.

```
final int count = 5;

try (DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int value = dis.readInt();
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(value));
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is a good solution for you, please _mark this answer as accepted_ (click on the check mark on the left, under the vote count).

Comment: I do not see the check mark on teh left... vote count?

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually reading from the file, but printing the binary representation of the first five characters of the name of the file. Use fin.read() to read bytes from the file.

You can also use DataInputStream to read 32 bit big endian integers directly, instead of reading them as 4 individual bytes.

Comment: I changed it to fin.read().  I am getting 1 0 0 0 5.  I am not getting content from the file?

Comment: The read method reads individual bytes, which have 8 bits. To read one 32-bit unit you have to read 4 bytes.

Comment: +1 for 'just use [`DataInputStream.readInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readInt%28%29)'